# Why won't this nested Average work when joining on null value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I am essentially trying to do this in a query (fake table names, but I've narrowed it down to something exactly like this with the schema I'm using:

```
from v in db.Vehicles
let avgVehicleModelMilesDriven = db.Vehicles.Where(av => av.ModelId == v.ModelId)
                                            .Average(av => av.MilesDriven)
select new
{
    v.Id,
    v.ModelId,
    v.MilesDriven,
    avgVehicleModelMilesDriven 
}
```

I'm expecting results like:

```
| Id | ModelId | MilesDriven | AverageModelMilesDriven |
  1    1         10,000        15,000
  2    1         20,000        15,000
  3    2         15,000        15,000
```

The above works fine, but let me introduce a schema change that breaks things. Assume that ModelId can be null. I would now expect results like this:

```
| Id | ModelId | MilesDriven | AverageModelMilesDriven |
  1    1         10,000        15,000
  2    1         20,000        15,000
  3    2         15,000        15,000
  4    null      5,000         5,000
```

Instead, I get the following exception: `The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type.`. This indicates to me that the collection I'm trying to average on does not have any values. The only way I can get this to work is by casting the average selected value to a nullable `int` like so:

```
db.Vehicles.Where(av => av.ModelId == v.ModelId)
           .Average(av => (int?)av.MilesDriven)
```

I end up with incorrect results like:

```
| Id | ModelId | MilesDriven | AverageModelMilesDriven |
  1    1         10,000        15,000
  2    1         20,000        15,000
  3    2         15,000        15,000
  4    null      5,000         null
```

I don't understand how this can be, since at least one vehicle of that type exists, otherwise it wouldn't be attempting to get the average for that type. I've also tried expressing this via a join, but get the same result. Am I missing something obvious? I can do this in two queries, but for this case I need to keep the result as an IQueryable. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

**EDIT** - Created a small test program that did the same thing but was working on a local collection of these objects instead of going to the database. It worked as expected. I'm guessing there's some issue with the SQL it tries to generate.

Comment: What is the sql that is being generated from your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.Where` statement into:

```
Where(av => av.ModelId == v.ModelId 
       || (!av.ModelId.HasValue && !v.ModelId.HasValue))
```

to get the averages of records without `ModelId`.

Comment: That did the trick! For anyone else looking, it would appear that the issue *is* with the SQL generation. In SQL, null comparison doesn't work the same, but when you write it like this, it's forced to generate SQL that will use `NOT NULL` for comparison, which allows this to work as expected.